# Splitting a string to use indexing to manipulate each word of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to manipulate each word of a string.

To do this I have followed the principle of using .split to split the string into a list, in order to manipulate each word from the list.

The tasks at hand requires me to uppercase alternating words of a string.
In this scenario I have been attempting to user a for loop to iterate alternating words from the list and uppercase them.

This wasn't my first initial approach, but this is where I stopped to seek help.
Each time I created a for loop to select a word from the list through indexing, it kept selecting the last word of the string no matter the indentation of the print or the number within the square brackets.

The task then requires me to join the string together which I understand to do, just struggling on selecting and manipulating a word from the list.

```py
string = "Python pythonating pythonators pyhthons pythonation"

split_string = string.split()

print(split_string)

for word in split_string:
    split_string = word[1].upper()
print(word)
```

Comment: indent your last line 4 spaces to see each word printed in the list. Note though that your code attempts to reset the list each iteration.

Comment: The description is unclear, please show an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
'''

string.upper() method captitalize the string
Alternate word is detected by the condition if index % 2 == 0

'''
st = "Python pythonating pythonators pyhthons pythonation"

split_string = string.split()

#method1: by using usual for loop

for i in range(len(split_string)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        split_string[i] = split_string[i].upper()
print(split_string)

#method2: python one-liner

split_string = [x.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(split_string)]

print(split_string)

#output(in both cases):
['PYTHON', 'pythonating', 'PYTHONATORS', 'pyhthons', 'PYTHONATION']
['PYTHON', 'pythonating', 'PYTHONATORS', 'pyhthons', 'PYTHONATION']
```

Comment: Do you disagree that this question is a duplicate?

Comment: I think the OP wants to capitalize the whole word btw, not just the first letter.

Comment: Yes, realized immediately the moment I posted. And edited immediately

Comment: @JonSG, I didn't check that since there are plenty of questions in stack overflow. Also I'm new to stack overflow. As it looked like the person seemed to be new to python, wanted to help and started typing.

Comment: It is great that you want to help. Thanks for that. In the future I encourage you to see if there is already an answer to a question, particularly one with a simple answer. You help just as much pointing the user to an authoritative answer as you do by generating a new answer. For SEO reasons, it would be better for SO to have one question and answer like this rather than many.